# Get child where parent id using java api

Tags: elasticsearch

I have "organizations" index structure :

```
{
 "organization" : {
    "properties" : {
        "id" : { "type" : "long" },
        "name" : { "type" : "string" }
    }
 }
}
```

and another index "campaigns" :

```
{
 "campaign" : {
    "properties" : {
        "id" : { "type" : "long" },
        "name" : { "type" : "string" }
    },  
    "_parent" : {
         "type" : "organization"
    }
 }
}
```

when i search in campaigns that has specific organization id :

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.hasParentQuery(SearchEntityEnum.ORGANIZATION.getType(), QueryBuilders.queryString("*" + keyword.replaceAll(" ", "* *") + "*").field(SearchEntityFieldNames.CommonFieldNames.NAME)
                .analyzeWildcard(true)));
        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(SearchEntityEnum.CAMPAIGN.getIndex())
                .setTypes(SearchEntityEnum.CAMPAIGN.getType())
                .setSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_AND_FETCH)
                .setQuery(qb)
                .execute().actionGet();
```

This error occur :

> `org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[-RCGH_JbTmeTGDSvWp9_wA][campaigns][2]: SearchParseException[[campaigns][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_parent":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"**","fields":["name"],"analyze_wildcard":true}},"parent_type":"organization"}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[campaigns] [has_parent] query configured 'parent_type' [organization] is not a valid type]; }{[-RCGH_JbTmeTGDSvWp9_wA][campaigns][1]: SearchParseException[[campaigns][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_parent":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"**","fields":["name"],"analyze_wildcard":true}},"parent_type":"organization"}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[campaigns] [has_parent] query configured 'parent_type' [organization] is not a valid type]; }{[-RCGH_JbTmeTGDSvWp9_wA][campaigns][4]: SearchParseException[[campaigns][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_parent":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"**","fields":["name"],"analyze_wildcard":true}},"parent_type":"organization"}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[campaigns] [has_parent] query configured 'parent_type' [organization] is not a valid type]; }{[-RCGH_JbTmeTGDSvWp9_wA][campaigns][0]: SearchParseException[[campaigns][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_parent":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"**","fields":["name"],"analyze_wildcard":true}},"parent_type":"organization"}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[campaigns] [has_parent] query configured 'parent_type' [organization] is not a valid type]; }{[-RCGH_JbTmeTGDSvWp9_wA][campaigns][3]: SearchParseException[[campaigns][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":{"has_parent":{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"**","fields":["name"],"analyze_wildcard":true}},"parent_type":"organization"}}}}}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[campaigns] [has_parent] query configured 'parent_type' [organization] is not a valid type]; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday. I found out that the parent and child types both need to be in the same index in order for the parent to be visible to the child.

In this example, `organization` and `campaign` are different types in different indexes. You will need to create one index with both of these types defined within it. Everything else I believe is good here so let me know if you have any further issues.

Comment: I already have one cluster, one node and i already set the "max_local_storage_nodes: 1" in my config

Comment: I also had one cluster and one node, but the important thing is that these two types must be in the same index. One node contains multiple indexes.

Answer (score -1):

I believe (might be wrong) that you should define `campaigns` as a `type` within `organizations` index. also you should set `routing` to `true` to make this works.

Comment: As in elasticsearch Parent/Child http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/ there are no define for child inside parent , as it become nested not Parent/Child, and when make routing to false it automatically make it true in Parent/Child.